# Geometric Sequence convergance without Taylor

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So lately I have observed the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux7vl6zXxj0&t=6s

The nice fellow on this video explained why this following property is correct
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$ 
as long as $|x|<1$

I did not quite understand two things:

1.the long devisioning he did in order to get the power seirie from the fraction of one over X minus one

2.why is it true only if $|x|<1$, why does this condition apply?

Thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: If $|x|\ge1$ then $|x^n|\not\to0$ so the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The video is not very rigorous, which is why you aren't able to determine why $|x|<1$ is needed. The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ really just means $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n).$$
Clearly this limit does not exist if $x=1$. Suppose $x\ne 1$.
We attempt to show that this limit is equal to $1/(x-1)$ by showing that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left| (1+x+\cdots+x^n)-\frac{1}{1-x} \right|=0.
$$
Note that for any $n$, we have
$$
\left| (1+x+\cdots+x^n)-\frac{1}{1-x} \right|
= \left|\frac{1}{1-x}\right||(1-x)(1+x+\cdots+x^n)-1|$$
$$
= \left|\frac{1}{1-x}\right||(1+x+\cdots+x^n)-(x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n+1})-1|$$
$$= \left|\frac{1}{1-x}\right||-x^{n+1}|
= \left|\frac{1}{1-x}\right||x|^{n+1}.
$$
Now $|x|^{n+1}$ goes to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinty if and only if $|x|<1$. In conclusion
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
if and only if $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the video much, so I will give you hints to understand this property by your own in a very easy and nice way.

Let us set $S_N= \sum_{n=0}^N x^n$ for $N\in \mathbf N$ and lets consider $|x|<1$. Just follow my three steps.

Step 1: Proof $S_N (1-x) = 1-x^N$ (telescop sum).

Step 2: Divide by $1-x\neq 0.$

Step 3: Calculate the limit $N\to \infty$ (and do not forget the definition of a series).

Answer (score 0):

The basic identity,
true for any $x$
and positive integer $n$
is that
$(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
=1-x^{n}
$.
This is readily
proved by induction.

Therefore,
if $x \ne 1$,
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
=\dfrac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}
=\dfrac{1}{1-x}-\dfrac{x^{n}}{1-x}
$
or
$\dfrac{1}{1-x}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
=\dfrac{x^{n}}{1-x}
$.

I will now show that
if
$0 < x < 1$
then
$x^n \to 0$
and if
$ x > 1$
then
$x^n \to \infty$.
The case $x < 0$
is handled by 
replacing $x$ by $-x$
and writing
$\dfrac{1}{1+x}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^kx^k
=\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{n}}{1+x}
$.

Note:
What follows is not original.

The basic inequality used
is Bernoulli's,
which states that
$(1+a)^n
\ge 1+na
$
if $a \ge 0$
and $n$ is a positive integer.
This is readily proved by induction.

If $x > 1$
then
$x = 1+y$
where $y > 0$.
Therefore
$x^n
=(1+y)^n
\ge 1+ny
\gt ny$ and this $\to \infty$
as $n \to \infty$
for any $y > 0$.

If $0 < x < 1$,
then
$x = \dfrac1{1+y}$
where
$y
=\dfrac1{x}-1
$
satisfies
$y > 0$.
Therefore
$x^n
=\dfrac1{(1+y)^n}
\le \dfrac1{1+ny}
\lt \dfrac1{ny}
\to 0
$
as $n \to \infty$.